# How to measure coverage in Python Hypothesis stateful testing?

Tags: python, testing, stateful, python-hypothesis

I test a certain functionality of a system using Hypothesis Stateful testing which generates many random sequences. In order to compare the results, I have written a model using Automat library which is also a statemachine. I would like to understand the coverage obtained using stateful test cases. As this testing is at integration level, I wouldn't want to find the code coverage. Something like a model coverage might help to understand how far the stateful test cases cover the model.

My question is: Does that seem like a good idea? Or is there a better option to obtain coverage of test cases from Hypothesis? Could someone please guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever coverage measurement you want is independent from Hypothesis, so you measure it in whatever way you usually would.  All Hypothesis does is call your code many times with arbitrary inputs!